# using four dependency together creating out of memory error, java

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

In my maven project i am using these 4 dependency together

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
<artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
<version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency><!--
<dependency>
<groupId>fr.pilato.elasticsearch.river</groupId>
<artifactId>fsriver</artifactId>
<version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
<artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I commented one by one But still getting same error. If i commented these 4 together them my error i removed.

Whats wrong with these dependencies?

Error when running webdeploy.dat

```
     jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.5.Final:deploy (deploy-web) @ -web ---
    Exception in thread "" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.StreamUtils.copyStream(StreamUtils.java:52)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.InputStreamEntry$InMemoryEntry.initialize(InputStreamEntry.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient$ReadAttachmentInputStreamRequestHandler$1.exec
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$2$1.doExecute(AbstractMessageHandler.java:296)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$AsyncTaskRunner.run(AbstractMessageHandler.java:518)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Comment: you're getting out of memory from your IDE, or from Maven, or from the application that you are developing?

Comment: updated. Error coming when trying to deploy by webdeploy.dat

Comment: Now i tried by commenting last three. After commenting last three there is no error. So may be there is some problem with last three.